# Python PolynomialFeatures transforms data into different shape from the original one

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, polynomials

I'm using sklearn's PolynomialFeatures to preprocess data into various degree transformations in order to compare their model fit.
Below is my code:

```js
    from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn.preprocessing import PolynomialFeatures
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
np.random.seed(0)
# x and y are the original data
n = 100
x = np.linspace(0,10,n) + np.random.randn(n)/5
y = np.sin(x)+n/6 + np.random.randn(n)/10
# using .PolynomialFeatures and fit_transform to   transform original data to degree 2
poly1 = PolynomialFeatures(degree=2)
x_D2_poly = poly1.fit_transform(x)
#check out their dimensions   
x.shape
x_D2_poly.shape
```

However, the above transformation returned an array of (1, 5151) from the original x of (100, 1). This is not what I have expected. I couldn't figure out what's wrong with my code. It will be great if someone could point out the error of my code or misconception on my part.
Should I use alternative methods to transform original data instead?

Thank you.

Sincerely,

[update]
So after I used x = x.reshape(-1, 1) to transform the original x, Python does give me the desired output dimension (100, 1) via poly1.fit_transform(x). However, when I did a train_test_split, fitted the data, and tried to obtain predicted values:

```js
x_poly1_train, x_poly1_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x_poly1, y, random_state = 0)
linreg = LinearRegression().fit(x_poly1_train, y_train)
poly_predict = LinearRegression().predict(x)
```

Python returned an error message:

```js
shapes (1,100) and (2,) not aligned: 100 (dim 1) != 2 (dim 0)
```

Apparently, there must be somewhere I got the dimensional thing wrong again. Could anyone shed some light on this?

Thank you.

Comment: I've answered your edited question as well, but since I did answer your first question, would you mind accepting the answer?

Comment: Thanks again. I apologize for not having up-voted your answer sooner as I was a bit preoccupied with comprehending the reshape() thing... :p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to reshape your x like

```
x=x.reshape(-1,1)
```

Your x had shape (100,) not (100,1) and fit_transform expects 2 dimensions.
The reason you were getting 5151 features is that you were seeing one feature for each distinct pair (100*99/2 = 4950), one feature for each feature squared (100), 1 feature for first power of each feature (100), and one the 0th power (1).

Response to your edited question:
You need to call [transform](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.PolynomialFeatures.html#sklearn.preprocessing.PolynomialFeatures.transform) to convert the data you wish to predict on.

Comment: Thanks! I checked out the documentation, it says the -1 means "[T]he new shape should be compatible with the original shape" and when one enters reshape(-1, 1), it means we want Python to figure out "the length of the array and remaining dimensions" so that it corresponds to the original shape. Am I conceiving this correctly?

Comment: using -1 means "figure out this dimension based on the other supplied dimensions. In this case, we're saying we want 1 column, and 100/1 rows.